# Remove Title Bar in ImGui

Tags: c++, glfw, titlebar, imgui

I would like to know that how do I remove the title bar from an ImGui Window. I am using C++ with GLFW for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`ImGuiWindowFlags_NoTitleBar`](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/0a154b30ad0f628256e3cd61b50ceb0840a1f335/imgui.h#L951) flag when creating the window:

```
ImGui::Begin("Window Name", &is_open, ImGuiWindowFlags_NoTitleBar);
// ... render window contents ...
ImGui::End();
```

An example of this and other flags you can use on an ImGui Window is located in [`imgui_demo.cpp`](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/imgui_demo.cpp).

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much for your help. It worked!. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @real_dev04 Hi, if the answer was helpful to you, you may [upvote it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to make it easier to find later by others.

Comment: I can't, because it's saying `Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded`  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To hide the title string for any ImGui element, you can also write ## in front of your title string. Eg: ImGui::Button("##Button", ImVec2(20, 20));